# didDiscoverPeripheral not called

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I need to send ASCII-codes via bluetooth to the third-party device.
Hope it's possible to do with spp. I could be wrong in terminology. I don't know enough this programming area.

In `centralManagerDidUpdateState` I'm scanning for peripherals:

```
CBUUID *cbuuidService = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0x1101"];
NSArray *service = @[ cbuuidService ];
NSDictionary *options = @{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES };
[central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:service options:options];
```

but `didDiscoverPeripheral` never called.

I tried to scan without services and it has the same effect.

What am I doing wrong? What `cbuuid` do I need and where can I find it? Thank for any help.

Comment: Did you set the Delegate? Do you have any Bluetooth Low-Energy (and not classical bluetooth, the question of CBUUID made me wonder) devices to find?

Comment: yes, I set the delegate so: m_centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil]; About BLE, I use iPad Air and MacBook Air in pair. no third-party device yet.

Comment: just I'm trying to make some connection between two devices while I don't have an original device. but it found nothing

Comment: Do you get any result if you _don't_ pass a list of services into `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:`? - i.e. if you pass nil?

Comment: I've nothing. and the state of central manager is CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn

Comment: Is one of them a Peripheral and the other one Central? If not, I suggest you use an app like LightBlue that can simulate a peripheral (your next third party device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have one device act as a central (which you do) and one as a peripheral device. So assuming that you use your MB Air as the central, you need to start a CBPeripheralManager on your iPad and have it publish and advertise a service. Then you should be able to discover it on your MB.

I guess the easiest way would be to get a working peripheral (e.g. a heart rate belt), so you can familiarize yourself with the usage of CBCentralManager. Then you could start implementing your own peripheral.

PS: I am not sure it is correct to put `0x` at the beginning of the identifier.

Comment: Thanks, I understood because of your explanation

Comment: what about a bluetooth keyboard or another iphone instead of a heart rate belt?

Because frankly i am not able to discover any peripheral. I am even scanning for all services and still nothing found. 

  [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:service options:options];

Answer (score 1):

Believe CoreBluetooth is very hard to use.

Instead of working with that messy framework use LGBluetooth (It woks over CoreBluetooth).

```
    [[LGCentralManager sharedInstance] scanForPeripheralsByInterval:10
                                                         completion:^(NSArray *peripherals)
     {
     }];
```

here is a example of scanning by interval.

Check it out
https://github.com/l0gg3r/LGBluetooth